# Problem with javax.xml.transform.Transformer. Empty element not showing properly in editor but in Browser

Tags: java, xml, dom, transform

I have used javax.xml.transform.Transformer and javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory and org.w3c.dom.Element and org.w3c.dom.Node to create XML file as per my requirement. Its creating XML successfully. The only problem is :

<MYADDRESS NAME="AA00001"> 
           <ATTN1>a</ATTN1>
           **<ADDRESS></ADDRESS>**  // This is empty ADDRESS element/tag. 
           <STATE>AA</STATE> 
           <ZIP>1</ZIP> 
      </MYADDRESS>

The <ADDRESS></ADDRESS> shows in browser as <ADDRESS/> where as in editor like notepad, wordpad it is shown as <ADDRESS><ADDRESS>. I want it to be displayed as <ADDRESS/> when the file is opened in Editor also.

Any idea ?
Thanks for help !

Answer (score 1):

You are aware, that `<ADDRESS></ADDRESS>` and `<ADDRESS/>` are identical, right? The browser just happens to collapse the former into the latter. From the point of view of an XML parser, there's no difference.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to configure the transform to collapse empty elements in the serialized output (like the text file). A quick look at the [list of properties](http://xml.apache.org/xalan-j/usagepatterns.html#outputprops) shows, that there is no such option.

So I think you'll have to implement and provide your own content handler (`xalan:content-handler` property). Maybe you can just subclass the default one and change the serialization behaviour for empty elements.

Comment: Thank you both for the response. 
At http://www.jdom.org/docs/apidocs/org/jdom/output/Format.html
there is method setExpandEmptyElements which looks like working as per need. 

But is there any direct way to do it for javax.xml.transform.Transformer and org.w3c.dom ?

Comment: I doubt that. This Formatter just encapsulates XMLOutputter format options. And the XMLOutputter is designed to work with `org.jdom.Document` objects but you use the `org.w3c.dom.Document` type. jdom has a class to convert from `org.jdom.Document` to `org.w3c.dom.Document` but not vice versa.